# drawString not working - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to use drawString to draw a string that says game over, but it wont work. earlier in the code it works fine but for some reason it stops working.

Code(only the part that doesn't work):

```
private static void end(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(BG);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 40)); 
    g.drawString("GAME OVER!!", 10, 30);
}
```

Comment: what is the variable BG?

Comment: An out of context code block isn't enough to diagnose your problem. You'll need to provided a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: You could be drawing with same color as the background.

Comment: The color of the text is the same as the background...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the color to something besides BG for the String to show.

```
private static void end(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(BG);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 40)); 
    g.setColor(FG)  // Here
    g.drawString("GAME OVER!!", 10, 30);
}
```